# gulp src duplicates when multiple globs

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a file structure like this:

```
/js/a.js
/js/b.js
/js/(lots of other files).js
/jsOld/x.js
/jsOld/y.js
/jsOld/(lots of other files).js
```

I want a.js and b.js first, and all other files after that, because I use gulp-inject and order is important for me. Also I don't want duplicates.

So, I select files like this:

```
gulp.src(["a.js", "b.js", "js/**/*.js", "jsOld/**/*.js"])
```

As the result, x.js and y.js are included twice. I don't want that.
What am I doing wrong? Should this be working as I expect?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to spit the task on two:

1. include only **a.js** and **b.js**
2. include others and exclude **a.js** and **b.js** by adding `!` sign to path/file that should be excluded:

   ```
   gulp.src(["!/js/a.js", "!/js/b.js", "js/**/*.js", "jsOld/**/*.js"])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

While method include ab / inlcude all / exclude ab should also work, my core problem was different.

File name was a.js (lowercase), but gulp.src was with uppercase, like:

```
 gulp.src(["A.js", "b.js", "js/**/*.js", "jsOld/**/*.js"])
```